# How to update manually tomcat 7 7.0.28 to 7.0.47?

Tags: java

http://ryanfx.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/raspberry-pi-powered-android-controlled.html?m=1

Because I do this tutorial and used 7.0.28 version...I need new version because websocket jsr-356...
...
how to update Tomcat on Raspberry Pi, after installing it using sudo apt-get install tomcat7?

Comment: Here is the Apache Upgrade guide for upgrading from 7.0.x to 7.0.x: [http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Upgrading_7.0.x](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Upgrading_7.0.x)